# should enabled button if at least one check box checked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm trying to make the button active if at least one checkbox is selected,The button is activated if the last checkbox is selected, but when the first checkbox is selected, it is inactive

```js
 function chose(){
         var txt="";
      var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
      console.log(checkboxes);
      for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
       if(checkboxes[i].checked){
      document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
      txt = txt + checkboxes[i].value + " ";
      }
      else{
        document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
      }
      }
        var result=document.getElementById("result");
        result.innerHTML=txt;
        }
```

```html
<form action="" method="GET">
 <label for="user">Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="username" id="user" value="" placeholder="Input name">
 <input type="button" name="" value="Send" id="btn" disabled="true" onclick="chose()">
 IceCream:<input type="checkbox" name="one" id="param_1" value="IceCream" onchange="chose()">
 Chocolate:<input type="checkbox" name="one" id="param_2" value="Chocolate"  onchange="chose()">

</form>
```

Comment: Ah, the good old [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info), the slogan of Stack Overflow. You are designing your form wrong. Your "Send" button should be one with `type="submit"` which will prevent form submission automatically if any of required controls are missing their value. This is you attempting to reinvent the wheel. But, instead of the "Send" submit button, you might want the form to submit "two-way" -- then make "IceCream" and "Chocolate" submit buttons, as they should be, each with their own value (yes, submit buttons can have different values) and get rid of the "Send" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed your code, although you can achieve it many ways. :)

```js
 function chose(){
        var txt="";
        var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
        var flag = false;
        for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
          if(checkboxes[i].checked){
            flag = true;
            document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
            txt = txt + checkboxes[i].value + " ";
          }
        }
        if(!flag){
           document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true; 
        }
        var result=document.getElementById("result");
        result.innerHTML=txt;
   }
```

```html
<form action="" method="GET">
 <label for="user">Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="username" id="user" value="" placeholder="Input name">
 <input type="button" name="" value="Send" id="btn" disabled="true" onclick="chose()">
 IceCream:<input type="checkbox" name="one" id="param_1" value="IceCream" onchange="chose()">
 Chocolate:<input type="checkbox" name="one" id="param_2" value="Chocolate"  onchange="chose()">

 <span id="result"> </span>
</form>
```

Comment: Why can't we write here `if(!checkboxes[i].checked)?`or `checkboxes[i].checked == false` it does not work

Comment: You can't use this condition inside the loop. otherwise it will be always disabled if last checkbox is not select.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)

```js
function chose() {
  var checked = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="one"]:checked');
  document.getElementById('btn').disabled = !checked.length;

  var text = Array.from(checked).reduce(function(res, cb) {
    return res + cb.value + ' ';
  }, '');
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="GET">
  <label for="user">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="user" value="" placeholder="Input name">
  <input type="button" name="" value="Send" id="btn" disabled="true" onclick="chose()"> IceCream:
  <input type="checkbox" name="one" id="param_1" value="IceCream" onchange="chose()"> Chocolate:
  <input type="checkbox" name="one" id="param_2" value="Chocolate" onchange="chose()">
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```